# Object does not exist when trying to download image file from firebase storage flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have an image saved in my firebase storage and the URL to that image stored in my firebase database. I'm trying to download that image and store it in a file but whenever I try to writeToFile i'm getting an error saying the object does not exist yet it does exist and when i copy and paste the URL string I have in my database into the browser its showing the image. The error is as follows:

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error -13010, FIRStorageErrorDomain, Object testLogo.jpg does not exist.)

This is the code that i'm using to try and retrieve the file (snapshotData['logo] is the URL String field in my firebase database):

```
final RegExp regExp = RegExp('([^?/]*\.(jpg))');

final String fileName = regExp.stringMatch(Uri.decodeFull(snapshotData['logo'].toString()));
final Directory tempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
final File file = File('${tempDir.path}/$fileName');

final StorageReference ref = storage.ref().child(fileName);
final StorageFileDownloadTask downloadTask = ref.writeToFile(file);
```

Really hoping there is a solution to this i've been searching but all the code suggestions i've tried are not working

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, this exceptions mean more type of errors from firebase.

Often, the problem is with the setting of the firestore rules.

You can also look here for more details about that:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1888#issuecomment-431544373